# Constructor values are empty after posting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model

i've recently came across really strange issue, although just want to mention before it worked, but i've done a lot of changes and now my app is a bit screwed, so i had to restart a bit, but still i have this strange behaviour, basically there are 2 things but i think they are related to each other!

So i have this kind of model:

```
public class MyModel
{
        [Required]
        public string Username{ get; set; }

        public UserLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

And user Location is:

```
public class UserLocation
    {
        public UserLocation()
        {
            if (CountryId != null)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        [Required]
        public string CountryId { get; set; }
...
}
```

So In my view i had this correctly build with the editor template, and when nothing was filled in, it showed an error directly, but now, it doesnt how the error! But before it did!

Secondly, when i click on a button, so an httppost method is fired, first the constructor UserLocation is called, BUT countryID which is filled in, it shown as empty!!! What before was not the case, before i screwed a bit, the constructor was called with httppost and the values were set, like country id, i dont know why but my code in constructor Always fired, but not anymore.

The values are set and in debugging i can see it!

Any idea what is going wrong?

Update:

Here is my editor template, this is how it looks like, as you can see i have validateion message for

```
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.Countries, "---select--", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId)
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Update 2: Regarding the validation**

So I had @Html.EditorFor ... and it didn't validate client side, when i changed it to @Html.Partial ... with the everything the same and intact it started to validate client side, why that issue? Any idea and how to make it work with editorfor and client side validation?

HTML with editorfor looks like this:

```
<select name="Location.CountryId" id="Location_CountryId">
```

Html with partial looks like this:

```
<select name="CountryId" id="CountryId" data-val-required="The Country field is required." data-val="true">
```

Comment: The line `if (CountryId != null)` is pointless in your constructor since it will always be `null` when the object is being built. What are you really trying to accomplish there?

Comment: It is so strange but before it was working in constructor i had values, because it was httppost, and somehow i got values there and i could do some extra stuff, like fill in the other list or something. Can it be that i'm using editorFor and not html.partial?

Answer (score 0):

> it showed an error directly, but now, it doesn't show the error! But before it did!

Sounds like you have maybe disabled client side validation - check to make sure you have included the validation scripts i.e.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

and have the options enabled in the `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

---

> Secondly, when i click on a button, so an httppost method is fired, first the constructor UserLocation is called, BUT countryID which is filled in, it shown as empty!!! What before was not the case

This doesn't make sense to me, `CountryId` can only be set *after* the object is created (unless it's passed to into the constructor, which it isn't). Therefore the constructor *has* to be called before `CountryId` is set. This sort of code doesn't seem right anyway, if this is a ViewModel any sort of validation should really be done outside of the class - perhaps in a service layer or depending on how simple it is, the controller.

Comment: You're wrong that the viewmodel shouldn't validate itself. The core of what is wrong in the question is that there is what appears to be validation style code in the constructor. The bulk of viewmodel validation should be handled by attributes, and anything else by a custom validation method.

Comment: no everything is correct, as the other fields in the view are validated on required

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. A view model *shouldn't* validate itself, that's  the *validators* job and the data annotations help it do that. The point of the view model is to transport information to/from a view - that's it. Generally it shouldn't have *any* sort of business logic in there, however, if it's related to the view model specifically then their is no harm in  *some* code being in there. It doesn't make sense for a model to validate itself purely because the state of the model can be deemed "valid" depending on how it's being used.

Comment: yea i just wanted to populate some lists when the fiels is not empty, so i shouldnt do this in controller all the time i call it.

Comment: @Alnedru "*I just wanted to populate some lists when the field is not empty*" - IMO this should be done at the server side (e.g. controller/service layer).

Comment: @Alnedru - You're right that it isn't the model class evaluating the validation attributes, but what I'm getting at is that the author appears to want to use something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664420(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: i understood the problem, a bit, so it seems becaused i used @Html.EditorFor("",model.location) it wasn't validated client side, but only server side, when i changed it to @Html.Partial("partial",model.location) it started to validate client side, why this behavrior?